# Repetitive iteration over JavaScript object with delay

Tags: javascript, html

I have JavaScript object with quotes and I have HTML element which will be filled by these quotes. I want every quote to be there for 5 seconds. Also I want it to be repeated. So when the last quote is used, function starts again. So far I have this.

```
var quote = document.getElementById("quote");
var quotes = {
    "q1": "q1",
    "q2": "q2",
    "q3": "q3"
}

function quoteChange(){
    for (var key in quotes){
        quote.innerHTML = quotes[key];      
    };
};
quoteChange();
```

Comment: There is chunking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `setTimeout` that repeatedly calls `quoteChange`:

```js
var quote = document.getElementById("quote");
var quotes = {
    "q1": "q1",
    "q2": "q2",
    "q3": "q3"
}

let i = 0;
const quoteStrings = Object.entries(quotes);
function quoteChange(){
  quote.textContent = quoteStrings[i][0] + ' : ' + quoteStrings[i][1];
  i = (i + 1) % quoteStrings.length;
  setTimeout(quoteChange, 5000);
}
quoteChange();
```

```html
<span id="quote"></span>
```

Not sure why `quotes` is an object, it would make more sense as an array, given what you're using it for.

Make sure to use `textContent` when you're setting *text content* - only use `innerHTML` when you're inserting an HTML string.

Comment: Thanks! Also I would like to use keys as the person who said that quote, is it somehow possible with your solution?

Comment: Use `Object.entries` to create an array of keys and values from the object - see edit. (you should post your requirements in your original question when you post it, not after people answer)